# Be notified when the Android app exits in background

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, exit

When my Android app is minimized and other apps are opened my app continues to work in background. For example, it continues to show notifications. However, sometimes when too many other apps are opened, my app suddenly stops. I want my app be notified and a method be triggered when my app stops in such a situation.In Xamarin Android, is there any way for the app to get notified about this exit? Is there any way to prevent such unexpected exits?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/#ondestroy

Comment: No, there is no way .. you shouldn't depened on onDestroy, onDestroy is for clean up not for fx saving data